# Given a dataset with X, Y, Z coordinates in Python, how to generate a contour in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dataset consisting of something like this:

```
10 10 4.49872823
10 20 4.48713242
20 10 8.34512345
...
1000 1000 1.91882984
```

I can load this fine, and I have a means of transforming it into any array that I like.

The problem is that I'm trying to graph it using NumPy in a contour map.

```
import numpy as np
np.contour(X,Y,Z)
```

Which only accepts data on a grid using `numpy.meshgrid`.

Getting the X and Y dataset is no problem, but I can't seem to figure out what format `numpy.contour` wants the Z value to be in as the documentation is limited. Examples shown show a 3 by X scale array like so

```
array([2.34556123 4. 4.55345318]
      [4.23245217 5. 2.25376211]
      ...
      [9.14245561 6. 8.24562431])
```

Which is beyond the scope of the simple coordinate plot that I'm attempting to do.

Comment: I can't find the `countour` module in numpy? What version of numpy are you running.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the matplotlib.pyplot method matplotlib.pyplot.contour? This accepts a  numpy.meshgrid, documentation is linked below:

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how it accepts the Z coordinate, or how to transform my data from 3 vector dataset to the format that it wants. That documentation is not even clear how it wants the Z plot.